# zip not supporting -S option?

Tags: linux, zip

I run `zip -r9 -S --symlinks ../output.zip .` and get the error `zip error: Invalid command arguments (short option 'S' not supported)`. `zip --version` tells me

```
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.
```

I need to run this command in two places: In Docker (`lambci/lambda`) on windows, and on an actual-linux build server to use on AWS.

Why does zip say it doesn't support the switch? Can I do the same thing with tar instead? I still need the command to produce a "normal" .zip, not a gzip or a bzip or etc.

Comment: Have you read the man pages for zip to see what switches they support?

Comment: “Include system and hidden files”? Why would you need that? Design your software so you don’t.

Comment: @music2myear yes, and according to the manpages, I can use -S to include hidden files in my .zip

Comment: @DanielB I don't get to control what files get generated, and one of the files that gets generated is a .hidden file that needs to be included in the output zip, but I also can't just rename it because its name is not static

Comment: My guess would be that this version of zip does not care about the specifics of (some) Windows file systems which support these attributes. If this is the case it also wouldn't ignore files with these attributes, so there would be no need to specify this switch.

Comment: From `man zip`:-
`-S,  --system-hidden
 [MSDOS, OS/2, WIN32 and ATARI] Include system and hidden files.
 [MacOS] Includes finder invisible files, which are ignored otherwise.`
 So the option has no meaning on Linux, where you say you are using it (sorry about the formatting, which is restricted in comments).